# Does .class .class as a css selector type means its a CSS descendant Combinator?

Tags: css

Are both CSS selectors the same as a CSS descendant combinator?

```
div p {
    color: #F00;
}

.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are descendant combinator selector, but the second has higher specificity (*if they apply to the same element*).

Answer (score 0):

yes both of them are descendant rule

As per the [spec doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

> A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by
>   white space. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an
>   element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

So any two selectors separated by a space constitutes a descendant selector.